# Как запретить datetimepicker смотреть во вчерашний день

Tags: c#, winforms

Как запретить устанавливать дату раньше текущей в datetimepicker?

Answer (score 6):

Поставь свойство `DateTimePicker.MinDate` на текущую дату.